# How to use C++ /WinRT HttpRequestMessage with Custom POST Body and HttpFormUrlEncodedContent (UWP App)

Tags: http, post, uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

In Windows 10, 1803 it is possible to call the WinRT from standard conforming C++. The C++ /CX language extensions are not required anymore.

I already know how to send a post Request to a Server using the HttpRequestMessage Class:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp")

#include "pch.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Web.Http.Filters.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Web.Http.Headers.h"
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <string_view>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Web::Http;
using namespace Windows::Web::Http::Filters;
using namespace Windows::Web::Http::Headers;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace std::literals;
using namespace std;


IAsyncAction HttpClientExample(Uri uri)
{
    HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter;
    HttpClient httpClient(filter);
    HttpRequestMessage loginRequest(HttpMethod::Post(), uri);

    try
    {

        auto response{ co_await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(loginRequest) };
        HttpCookieCollection cookieCollection =     filter.CookieManager().GetCookies(uri);
        wcout << cookieCollection.Size() << L" cookies found." << endl;

        for (HttpCookie cookie : cookieCollection) {
            wcout << L"Name: " << cookie.Name().c_str() << endl;
            wcout << L"Domain: " << cookie.Domain().c_str() << endl;
            wcout << L"Path: " << cookie.Path().c_str() << endl;
            wcout << L"Value: " << cookie.Value().c_str() << endl;
        }
    }
    catch (winrt::hresult_error const& ex)
    {
        // Details in ex.message() and ex.to_abi().
    }
}

int main() {

    init_apartment();

    Uri uri{ L"http://www.google.com/"sv };

    HttpClientExample(uri);

    Sleep(10000);
}
```

How do i set a Custom Header using HttpFormUrlEncodedContent and how do i set custom content in the POST Body?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: An `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request sends its content as part of the URL (as opposed to the body), as a list of key-value pairs (`<uri>?<key1>=<val1>&<key2>=<val2>&...`). You can set up a [HttpFormUrlEncodedContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpformurlencodedcontent) object by passing the key-value pairs into its constructor. You can assign headers by accessing its [Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpformurlencodedcontent.headers#Windows_Web_Http_HttpFormUrlEncodedContent_Headers) property.